# download with projectname in svn ant

Tags: java, ant, svnant

Hi I wanted to download one javaproject form svn repository. for that I am using
ant script to getch the project from the URL. Following is my ant script.

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />

    <taskdef name="svn" classname="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
    <target name="checkout">
        <svn  javahl="false" svnkit="true" >
            <checkout url="https://svndomain:8080/svn/proejcts/tags/DBproject/client/java/de.db.urlloader.config.test"  destpath="../Checkout" />
        </svn>
    </target>
```

Here `de.db.urlloader.config.test` is the java project.

But what happens is here it does download only the contents inside the java project into the Checkout folder. It does not download with the project name. I want the output in the following way

`Checkout ->de.db.urlloader.config.test->contents` of the java project

Now the output comes in the following way

```
  Checkout ->contents of the java project
```

Comment: Changing destpath="../Checkout/de.db.urlloader.config.test" helps?, as it equivalent to running 'svn co' to your required target directory

Comment: No.then the build fails if I give de.db.urlloader.config.test. I think both the project name and directory name should not be same. It does not make any sense if we think.  I get the following error.de.db.urlloader.config.test appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater

Comment: Ah, Whether your 'https://svndomain:8080/svn/proejcts/tags/DBproject/client/java/de.db.urlloader.config.test' is a file?. I think SVN doesn't allow you to checkout a single file. You can checkout a directory. I don't see any problem in checking out 'svn co http://my-proj-root/tags/someDir      Checkout/someDir'

Comment: No that is not a single file. It is a single folder.I mean destpath="../Checkout/de.db.urlloader.config.test" which is a single folder which contains multiple folders and files. Now I am not able to checkout de.db.urlloader.config.test project folder. Its get downloaded only the contents inside the folder. And also I am not able to define the project name (de.db.urlloader.config.test) as the   folder name in the ant chekcout folder name.